# Unable to remap Local Work spaces to TFS server

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs

Good morning all;

I have a problem.  I was developing on Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise.  I had a project with many branches.  They were properly mapped to the workspace on the server.

Then I was out of work for several weeks.  During that period my user account timed out for inactivity and was deleted from the TFS server.  When I returned the admins had to establish a new user account.  As a result of this, the workspace was no longer mapped to local workspace folder.

When I first attempted to remapped, it appeared to go well but in fact I actually mapped to an incorrect folder.  When I went into Workspaces edit to correct this, I got an error message saying "The path "localWorkPath"/"branch" is already mapped in workspace "workspacename;DomainUsername.'

In the MS forum "Archived Forums V Team Foundation Server - Source and Version Control" post "How do I reset the local location of a file in source control?", He was able to figure out his issue: "My problem was that I deleted the workspace associated with my local copy of the library in its previous location but I did not remove the binding to that location. When I moved the files and uploaded the change into source control the binding remained and so there was a disconnect between the source control binding location and the active workspace."

Based on what I am seeing I figure my issue is the same due to the removal and re-adding of my user.  Unfortunately, he did not go into detail, on how to resolve the issue.

Based on this, the only thing I can see is to go into the proj file of every branch and remove the mapping then remap everything individually.

However as this is so absofrackinglutely tedious and labor intensive, I would have thought that MS would have come up with a process to resolve this.  Does anyone know if this is true?  All advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In order to fix it I used [TFS Sidekicks](http://www.attrice.info/downloads/index.htm#tfssidekicks2015) it's a GUI for TFS that provides an option to scan and delete actual workspace definition from the server. You can do the same from the command line [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y901w7se(VS.80).aspx) but in my opinion the first option is easier.

Comment: I am pretty sure I do not have the permissions needed to carry this out on the TFS server.

Comment: I definitely do not have the required permissions to access the server's command line.  In fact my new user has fewer permissions than the original did.

Answer (score 0):

Roman's answer is correct but may not be enough.
Since workspaces are cached locally, after removing them from the server (using TF Sidekicks or command line) you may require clearing the local cache.
Clear the local cache using the following *tf.exe* command:

```
TF workspaces /remove:*
```

Comment: after doing this what would I expect to see in the Visual Studio GUI?  would deleting the workspace mapped to me affect the other developers using TFS?  What kind of permissions would I need?  What will happen to my local projects?

Comment: The local workspace would be removed and you will no loger see the mappings in Visual studio. Also, all check-out files will be released in TFS. The local files will not be affected or removed.